# max_execution time limit php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for the last couple of days.
I have a site where I crawl news and that works perfectly.
Recently however, I've encountered a problem with my analyzer_script as it appears to exceed the time limit my web host has set. Apparently there is an max_execution time at about 1 minute, and my script takes way longer than that. And I'm not able to adjust that in the php.ini script since I'm hosting my website on a public server.
What can I do? Do I need to rewrite my script?

I appreciate your help!
My script is below:

```
<?php
    $array = array();
    $sub_array = array();
    $analyzer_ids = array();

$res5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,status FROM statuz ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($res5);

$status = $row5['status'];
$status_id = $row5['id'];

if($status == 2) {

    $res1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tag, id FROM tags");
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
        $tag = $row1['tag'];
        $id = $row1['id'];

        $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sub_tag FROM sub_tags WHERE tag_id = '$id'");
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
            $sub_tag = $row2['sub_tag'];
            $sub_tag = strtolower($sub_tag);
            $sub_array[] = $sub_tag;
        }

        $array[] = array('tag_id' => $id, 'tag' => $tag, 'sub_tag' => $sub_array);
        $sub_array = array();
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO analyzer_queue (crawler_id, status)
    (SELECT id,0 FROM crawlers)");

    $initial_res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT crawler_id,id FROM analyzer_queue WHERE status = '0'");
    while($initial_row = mysqli_fetch_array($initial_res)) {

        $analyzer_id = $initial_row['id'];
        $start_crawler_id = $initial_row['crawler_id'];
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE analyzer_queue SET status = '1' WHERE crawler_id = '$start_crawler_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $analyzer_ids[] = $analyzer_id;

                $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cr.title, cr.content, cr.id
                FROM crawler_results cr
                INNER JOIN crawlers c
                ON c.newspaper_id = cr.newspaper_id
                WHERE c.id = '$start_crawler_id'
                AND status = '3'
                LIMIT 10");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

                    $article_id = $row['id'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $content = $row['content'];

                    $content = strip_tags($content);
                    $content = strtolower($content);
                    $title = strtolower($title);


                    $count = array();
                    foreach ($array as $tag) {
                        $regex = '/(?:\b' . preg_quote($tag['tag'], '/');
                        foreach ($tag['sub_tag'] as $sub) {
                            $regex .= '\b)|(?:\b' . preg_quote($sub, '/');
                        }
                        $regex .= '\b)/i';
                        $count_content = preg_match_all($regex, $content, $count_content);
                        $count_title = preg_match_all($regex, $title, $count_title);
                        $count_total[$tag['tag']] = $count_content + $count_title;
                        $total_count = $count_total[$tag['tag']];

                        $tag_name = $tag['tag'];

                        $res5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = '$tag_name'");
                        $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($res5);

                        $tag_id = $row5['id'];


                        if($total_count != 0) {
                            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO article_tags (article_id,tag_id,count_tags) VALUES('$article_id','$tag_id','$total_count')");
                        }

                        echo$count_total[$tag['tag']];
                        echo"<br /><br />";
                    }

                    echo"<pre>";
                    print_r($count_total);
                    echo"</pre>";

                    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crawler_results SET status = '2', analyzer_id = '$analyzer_id' WHERE id = '$article_id'");
                }
                mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE analyzer_queue SET status = '2' WHERE crawler_id = '$start_crawler_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

        }
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crawler_results SET status = '4' WHERE analyzer_id NOT IN (".implode(',',$analyzer_ids).")");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE statuz SET status = '3' WHERE id = '$status_id'");
        print_r($analyzer_ids);

} else {
    echo"Not ready yet";
}




?>
```

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

[The original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776400/make-script-execution-to-unlimited)

Comment: Perfect KrustyBox! That was impressively fast! Whose answer do I accept? oliakaoil provided more details, but you were 3 minutes faster.

Comment: My code was all that you needed. I have less point than @oliakaoil... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ini_set` at the top of your script like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time' , 300 );
```

The above call would set max execution time of the script to five minutes. Here's the doc page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

If your host allows, you might also consider running this script via cron or some other scheduling daemon. PHP scripts run in the cli context usually have no execution time limit, or a much higher one.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question that fast oliakaoil! Unfortunately KrustyBox was 3 minutes faster than you, but you provided more details in your answer. What do I do?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm the least objective in answering your "what do I do" question :-), so I'll abstain.