# What is the maximum allowed value of max_execution_time in php.ini

Tags: php

I tried increasing the value of max_execution_time in php using

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 108000);
```

which equals to 30 hours. I was just playing with this value to crawl websites with large amount of data in it. But, I go this fatal error that said the maximum execution time cannot exceed 30 seconds. When I changed 108000 value to 300, my script executed for 5 minutes. I wonder what is the maximum allowed value for this thing in php?

Comment: i would suggest you to use php through CLI. It is not affected by `max_execution_time` and will work until it's finished.

Comment: I dont want to execute some script. Just wanted to know the maximum allowed value. I browsed the documentation but they didn't state it there.

Comment: 0 should remove the time limit altogether and let your script run forever (if it wants). is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [max\_execution time limit php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938773/max-execution-time-limit-php)

Comment: No, It's Not Duplicate. He Is Asking The Maximum Value For Maximum_Exection_Time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct answer in reference to Mjh's comment.**

Signature for parsing integer ini values:

```
ZEND_API long zend_ini_long(char *name, uint name_length, int orig);
```

Therefore the maximum value that can be entered into that field is: 2147483647

**Old answer.**

The only clue I could find was here:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_ini.h

```
#define php_ini_long    zend_ini_long
```

Which eventually leads back to:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_long.h

```
typedef int64_t zend_long;
```

That is a 64 bit integer, or:

```
−9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

EDIT: Correction.

```
// PHP x64
typedef int64_t zend_long;

// PHP x86
typedef int32_t zend_long;
```

So the max value is `PHP_INT_MAX`.

If you are getting errors saying it cannot exceed 30 seconds, this is because your server configuration has forbidden changing that value to anything above 30 seconds.

Comment: Since I was doing the same thing as you, I stumbled upon `INI_INT` macro, which turns out to be a wrapper for [zend_ini_long](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_ini.c#348) which calls [strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), which returns the long integer. Having dumped this wall of text in the comment, have my upvote, your answer is correct if my crawling through the code has been correct :)

Comment: @Mjh Does that mean it only returns a `long`, since it doesn't use `strtoll` for the 64 bit systems?

Comment: It appears so, it returns `long` always, unless I missed something obvious while browsing [lxr.php.net](http://lxr.php.net).

Comment: Then my answer is only half right.  If you post the correct one you can have a one up from me :P

Comment: I believe you can edit yours and include stuff from my comment, IMO it's better not to post too many "correct" answers :)

Comment: But when I changed this manually to 2147483647 in php.ini file, I still got the same fatal error. However, placing the code ini_set('max_execution_time', 2147483647); in a random php test file actually worked. Why did that happen?

Comment: I don't think `ini_set('max_execution_time', 2147483647);` is actually setting it to that value.  I did a similar test earlier with a 128 bit figure and it didn't complain.  This is limitation imposed by the web server.  See answer by @Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the manual [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> **seconds** The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

It maybe unlimited so perhaps for php the limit is just the maximum **int** value.

But there could be external factors, <strike>if I remember correctly *suhosin* patch have its own maximum execution time</strike> if executed from a web server *maybe* the server itself have some limit, looking at [php sources](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/main.c#L285) I've the impression also network timeouts may be a factor.

Comment: +1 for mentioning external factors. apache has a timeout directive and iis has a timeout function, both of which can pre-empt the setting of `max_execution_time`