# insert query not inputing 1 million results

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble cross computing and inserting the results from 2 different tables into another one,

**table structure**

> **2_o** contains 210 results
>
> **4_e** contains 5985 results
>
> **all_combinations** should theoretically contain after cross computing the results 210 * 5985 =
> 1,256,850 results

my query is working thus my only problem is that its not reaching the result that it should **1,256,850** and it seems that its not finishing and cutting every time on a different total. no idea why. 1,247,102 or 1,153,550 etc...

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mysql");
if (!$sql) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("numbers");
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO all_combinations (o1,o2,e1,e2,e3,e4) SELECT n2.o1, n2.o2, n4.e1, n4.e2, n4.e3, n4.e4 FROM 2_o AS n2, 4_e AS n4");
  echo "done";
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not input results. " . mysql_error());
}
```

?>

Comment: **STOP!** Before you go any further stop using Mysql_* as it is now deprecated. You need to look into using Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: may be you need to increase php function execution  time

Comment: @Option no need, its a one time use query

Comment: @knowledge.... how do i do that ?

Comment: refere this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15776426/2286537