# How to increase/remove server Gateway time-out limit

Tags: php, cloudflare

I am using a CRON Job to add large amount of data to MySQL Database. It will take  around 30 days for the script to add all pages.

But after 100 seconds, I get Gateway time-out, so i want to increase the gateway timeout limit. How can I do it?

I need to change cloudflare settings or my php settings?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is the format of your data.. like sql,excel,csv or somthing...??

Comment: I am using PHP Code to send data to MySQL

Comment: ok tell me the data format.?? or your contab statement ..??

Comment: sir, i do not understand, what type of format? Does that even matter, what is my code? I just want to know how to increase the time-out time sir

Comment: there is the possibility of more good and less time taking logic . Ok  increase your max_execution_time in php.ini or follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776400/make-script-execution-to-unlimited

Comment: I am adding like 1 million data, i don't think there is a faster way :p, and thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148573/discussion-between-dharmendra-singh-and-josh-poor).