# Laravel - Hash::make(), how not to exceed the execution time?

Tags: php, laravel, time, hash, execution

I'm using Laravel 8.23.1, PHP 7.4.1

I need to import 800-1000 users from .csv. I'm using Maatwebsite\Excel for import.

The main problem is that `Hash::make()` is taking too much time, making it impossible not to exceed the maximum execution time.

I heard about running the command through Artisan CLI, but I don't know how to make this work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can very easily create a command: `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands`.

Comment: Or you can just disable the timeout while importing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776400/make-script-execution-to-unlimited - Don't forget to revert the timeout after you're done though.